# When an app is displayed via a Citrix client on Windows, is the user seeing an image or a real app?

Tags: windows, citrix

When a user interacts with an app that is delivered via a Citrix - what does the user see? Is it a full app with real Windows, or just an image like in RDP?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It's rendered similar to RDP but over the HDX (formerly ICA) protocol (vs the RDP protocol). Communication occurs on port 2598 by default (if using the Session Reliability feature) or 1494 (if that feature is disabled). The user is seeing a real app, but that app is running server side.